# Can summoned creatures take reactions?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, summoning, reactions

[Animate Dead](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=666) is used to summon a [Hollow Serpent](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=1872). An ally within the hollow serpent's reach is attacked, triggering Divine Guardian. Does the summon have a reaction with which it can use Divine Guardian?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Summons don't have reactions

[Summoned](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=154) creatures have the [Minion](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=109) trait. This trait includes the following:

> A creature with this trait can use only 2 actions per turn, **doesn't have reactions** [...]

(emphasis mine)

So no, the serpent can't use any reactions.